# Android: How to automatically display vertical scrollbar?

Tags: android, layout

I created a user form which fits the window in vertical orientation. When the user slides the keyboard the form doesn't fit the screen (horizontal orientation). I tried to add the scrollbar but it is not visible.

I would appreciate if anyone could show how to modify the following layout file in order to display scrollbar when the orientation is set to horizontal.

Thanks!

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:scrollbars="vertical" 
    android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true">
        ...
    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Remove the scrollbar attributes and wrap the whole thing in a `ScrollView`.

Answer (score 16):

You can't replace the LinearLayout with ScrollView because ScrollView only supports one Direct Child and LinearLayout may have many. So the only option i see is to wrap

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:overScrollMode="always" 
        android:isScrollContainer="true" 
        android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true" 
        android:scrollbarStyle="outsideInset" 
        android:scrollbars="vertical">
```

You can pick a variety of other attributes. These worked for my implementation. It is the first container in my layout.LinearLayout is a child of this container. Other UI elements are part of LinearLayout

Hope this helps... 
Alex

Comment: @VikasGupta you have two options for it.First through Programming i.e by using the following code:-InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(editTextField.getWindowToken(), 0); also through Manifest File your solution will be achieved by using the following code:-android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden".I think this will help you a lot in future.